# cut Direct3D texture with circular shape on a new texture OR change Alpha value of a part of pixels

Tags: textures, crop, pixel, direct3d

Hello and sorry my English.

I need to cut/crop a LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 with circle shape. On a new texture on same texture.

Can I change ARBG values for each pixel and with circle area equation change Alpha value to 255 (transparent) of external area?

Other way is create a new texture transparent and copy only pixels I need with circle shape.

How I don't know if I'm explained good....

I have this.
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjJUc.jpg)
And the new texture has to be like this
[Croped Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkH0V.jpg)
Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

This is a compositing/masking problem.  You can do it on the CPU or on the GPU.

To do it on the CPU, you can manipulate the pixels in the texture map directly with [IDirect3DTexture9::LockRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205913(v=vs.85).aspx).

To do it on the GPU, there are a number of techniques.  The simplest is probably to set a new texture as the current render target, use the stencil or alpha buffer to mask off a circular area, then draw the old texture onto the new one using a quadrilateral that fills the render target.

Answer (score 0):

If you already load this texture to `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9` interface there is no way to change it. The only way is to create new by some offscreen manipulation and shaders, or using texture staging with combiners and some circular mask (wich masks proper pixels as transparent). Or just create proper texture in Photoshop with aphamask and load it.

PS. Do not forget to enable blending state by `IDirect3DDevice9->SetRenderSate()`

Here is the example of generating procedural mask to texture.

Vertex shader.

```
struct VS_INPUT 
{
   float4 Position : POSITION0;

};

struct VS_OUTPUT 
{
   float4 Position : POSITION0;
   float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
   float2 Mask : TEXCOORD1;
};

VS_OUTPUT vs_main( VS_INPUT Input )
{
   VS_OUTPUT Output;

   Output.Position = Input.Position;
   Output.TexCoord = (Input.Position.xy - 1) * -0.5f;
   Output.Mask = Input.Position.xy;

   return( Output );

}
```

Pixel shader.

```
struct PS_INPUT 
{
   float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
   float2 Mask : TEXCOORD1;
};

sampler Texture0;

float4 ps_main(PS_INPUT Input) : COLOR0
{   
   float maskCoef = 0.0f;

   if ((Input.Mask.x * Input.Mask.x + Input.Mask.y * Input.Mask.y) < 1.0f)
   {
      maskCoef = 1.0f;
   } 

   return  maskCoef * tex2D(Texture0, Input.TexCoord);
}
```

The result will be.

[image]

the size of circle can be simple changed in condition check `if ((Input.Mask.x * Input.Mask.x + Input.Mask.y * Input.Mask.y) < 1.0f)` by replacing `1.0f` value with lesser `0.5f` for example will reduce mask on half.

Comment: Textures can certainly be changed.  Look at the `IDirect3DTexture9::LockRect` method.

Comment: @legalize: I am the shader guy and do not like this fixed-function stuff.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with fixed-function vs. shaders.

Comment: Really I don't need to use the LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 to create this image. I have one JPG or PNG and I need to create a new LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9  with circle shape.

Comment: I'm testing and soon reply you. Thanks

Comment: @SergiPanadero: Yes you can. You just create new texture and use it as render target.

Comment: @SergiPanadero: Shader will fill it with new data.